# Heroku - domain redirect. App displayed in a frame

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, heroku

I want to redirect myapp.herokuapp.com to mydomain.com.

What I was able to achieve with company that I bought a domain from (lets call them X) is to add new CNAME, so a `www.mydomain.com` displays `myapp.herokuapp.com` and that is OK.

What I also want to do is to be able to access the app without the need to write `www` before the rest of the address. It was said to me that I should change A record within domain configuration, but X company does not allow it. What I can (and what they recommended) is to set and option in domain configuration called `IP/URL/host redirect` to `myapp.herokuapp.com`.

Changing this makes my website available under the `mydomain.com` without the need to write `www` before, but what it also does is it displays the website in a frame.

What should I do to achieve this? Is this a heroku thing, the X company thing or should I change something in the way my website can be displayed?

Typing `www.mydomain.com` displays the website correctly - without the `<frameset><frame></frame></frameset>` tags.

Comment: Sounds like an X company thing. When you own a domain, you should be able to do whatever you want with its DNS, which includes setting an A record. If that's not the case, change registrars.

Comment: After a couple of tries I managed to set the mentioned option to host redirect. It removed the `A record` from my domain records and replaced it with a `CNAME record` setting the name to `mydomain.com` and the value to `myapp.herokuapp.com`. Still, the app is available under the `www` but when I try to type the url without it, it redirect me now to the X company home page.

Answer (score 0):

In the Heroku Dashboard **"Domains and Certificate"** section, add to your custom domains both domain names, `"www.mydomain.com"` and `"mydomain.com"`.

Make your DNS target the `"mydomain.herokuapp.com"` in both records.

Check https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains for more information.

Comment: I have read the guide already and plenty of other articles too. Seems like I should follow Dace Slutzkin advice and change the company.